# Why does every window fade when I rotate the desktop cube?

Tags: 10.10, compiz

I am setting up a laptop for a friend with Ubuntu 10.10. I turned on fancy visual effects and the "desktop cube" plugin as well. When I rotate the cube every window and even the wallpaper gets dark and desaturated. I tried looking into other plugins, even turning them off, other Gnome options, and I couldn't figure out why this fading happens. I've set up various computers with Ubuntu before but I have never seen such a problem.

How could I turn the fading off and keep the visual effects?

Comment: when you say fading or gets dark are you referring to the windows not responding?

Comment: That sounds like the default way for Ubuntu to display an application isn't responding (when visual effects are activated). Rotating the cube might be taking enough resources on your computer that it's causing all the running applications to freeze up while waiting for resources to be available.

Comment: I think the plugin that controls this is the Fade plugin. You'll need the Compiz Settings Manager to set the delay for fading to a longer period.

Comment: I know that darkening is the default for non-responsive windows, but that never happened with the desktop wallpaper. I'll check the Fade plugin the next time I meet my friend, and see if it settles the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck General Options -> Display Settings -> Lighting & you're good to go!  I'm just setting up my own 10.10 box & found the same problem.  Apparently it doesn't annoy some people.  Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

<s>If you have ADD helper enabled in your compiz-config, disable it. I'm guessing that is the one, because it fits the description well, and I've seen it do that before. Look to [this great guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) for more in depth information.</s>

Try adding `| !Class=Nautilus)` or `& !(Class=Nautilus)` to the Fading windows plugin to disable the desktop fading, but as for the other windows, I'm still not sure what is causing it.

Comment: I don't see an "Add Helper" module. Which module do you mean?

Comment: updated my answer, btw, that's exactly what it's called.

Comment: unfortunately changing it did not help with the problem :-/ The fading occurs only when I rotate the cube.

Comment: there are only two plugins that introduce this function (as far as I know, and the window fade plugin should not cause this issue, but I'll keep looking for a solution).

Comment: Is this only for mouse rotate or keyboard too?  Can you upload your CompizConfig preferences so others can try them.